# How should I handle Exact Duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, plagiarism

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309308/how-to-convert-converting-string-to-int-in-java) question, which asks how to convert a string to an int in java. Someone later flagged it as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java). Thing is though, it's an EXACT duplicate. The title is a little different, but the question content is EXACTLY the same, funny thing is, a user wrote an answer, when they should have closed it, as they have the correct gold tag badge to do so. Should I flag for moderator attention, or comment asking the gold tag badge user the close it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's plagiarism. Just other flag the question for moderator attention, explain that the user appears to of just copy/pasted an already existing question and posted it as his own. Include a link to the question the user copied.

Comment: Flexo killed it.